# Playing a Sound at Timed Intervals Within a Loop Whilst Having Other Code Continue to Execute

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I need to play a sound within an if statement within a loop, however, I need it played at 1 second intervals whilst still allowing for the following code within said loop to execute during the time in which the sound is being played. I need this to be able to occur an infinite number of times. Below is the relevant component of my code.

```
import pygame as p
import math as m

walkSound = p.mixer.Sound('walk.mp3')

while True:
    ...
    keysPressed = p.key.get_pressed()
    if keysPressed[p.K_UP]:
        walkSound.play()
        # the other code I need to execute
        tX += 2 * m.sin(startRot)
        tY += 2 * m.cos(startRot)
```

This of course loops that sound at very short intervals, so I tried using multi-threading to solve the issue.

```
import pygame as p
import math as m

walkSound = p.mixer.Sound('walk.mp3')

while True:
    ...
    keysPressed = p.key.get_pressed()
    if keysPressed[p.K_UP]:
        thread = T(target=walk_sound())
        thread.start()
        tX += 2 * m.sin(startRot)
        tY += 2 * m.cos(startRot)


    def walk_sound():
        if keysPressed[p.K_UP]:
            walkSound.play()
            i.sleep(1)
```

Whilst this fixes the aforementioned problem, the rest of the code will not execute until after second has elapsed.

Comment: have you heard of [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval)?

Comment: `T(target=walk_sound())` this is a bug, remove the function calling brackets like this to work `T(target=walk_sound)`, in short you are calling the function instead of passing it to a thread.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom event and set a timer for it :

```py
# Custom event
PLAY_SOUND = pg.USEREVENT
pg.time.set_timer(PLAY_SOUND, 1000)
```

Then in your event handler you will receive a PLAY_SOUND event at the interval you set :

```py
for evt in pg.event.get():
    if evt.type == pg.QUIT:
        exit()
    if evt.type == PLAY_SOUND:
        play_sound()
```